# Printing each array item in Xcode Playground?

Tags: xcode, swift2

When looping through an array and printing each item in the Playground, the output is `(x times)`. Where x is the count.

Rather than the count, is there a way to make the Playground output each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Playground, go to menu

> View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area

it will show the console where you'll be able to see the result of `print`.